# find array in array by key, and set value

Tags: php, arrays, object, recursion

So I have a function which loops through Objects recursive, cause some of Object have objects inside for example the **object** **Person** can contain **object** **Adress** and puts them into an array.

so basically this can be a structure from a model:

```
 [obj] Neededforexample
 - [obj] person
 -- [prop] first-name
 -- [obj] adress
 - SomeProperty
```

So the function which loops through it is completed:

```
private static function SetPropertiesArray($class,$parentClass = null){
    $object = new $class;
    $objectProperties = get_object_vars($object);
    foreach($objectProperties as $prop => $value){
        //echo $prop;
        if(class_exists($prop)){
            if($parentClass !== null){

                self::$_propertiesArray[$parentClass][$prop] = $value;
            }
            else{
                self::$_propertiesArray[$prop] = $value;
            }
            self::SetPropertiesArray($prop,$prop);
        }
        else{
            if($parentClass !== null){
                self::$_propertiesArray[$parentClass][$prop] = $value;
            }
            else{
                self::$_propertiesArray[$prop] = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    return self::$_propertiesArray;
}
```

This outputs this array:

```
"NeededForExample" => array(
  "Person" => null,
  "SomeProperty" => "Somevalue",
  "First-name" => "Firstname",
  "adress" => "HERE")
```

While I want:

```
"NeededForExample" => array(
  "Person" => array(
   "First-name" => "firstname",
   "adress" => array(
     "street" => "streetname"
   ) 
  ),
  "SomeProperty" => "Somevalue")
```

Comment: Could you post 1 or 2 elements in the original array containing your data/objects? This is so that we can see the Structure a bit.... You could do a `var_dump()` on your data and copy-paste the first 1 or 2 elements....

Comment: {"Person":{"SurName":null,"LastName":null,"BurgerServiceNummer":null,"Address":null},"Address":{"Street":null,"ZipCode":null,"City":null,"Country":null},"Message":null}

Comment: The line `if(class_exists($prop)){`; should it not read `if(class_exists($class)){` ? Because `$prop` seems like the Property of the `$class` in question and not the Class itself... and `get_object_vars` returns an Array containing the properties of an Object... but not the Class itself....

Comment: @Poiz yeah you're right should be this works fine tho since every models class included needs an object in my case but what you just said is true.

Comment: Something was tried below... instead of using Recursive function, 2 functions were used instead... check  it out & see how it plays out. You can check out the Demo here: https://eval.in/609466

Comment: @Poiz as you can see below I have created a sample code myself after struggling for an hour my code is working relaly well now and I am happy still thanks for the help! Your way will probably work to but since i've had so much trouble ill keep using mine which i believe is decent too!:) Take my upvote :D!

Answer (score 1):

The Code below may be pertinent to your case. But you may test it out [here](https://eval.in/609466) first.

```
    <?php

        $helper         = new Helper("Person", null);
        var_dump($helper->getPropertiesArray());



        class Helper{

            protected $Message;
            protected static $_propertiesArray = array();

            public function __construct($class, $parentClass) {
                self::SetPropertiesArray($class, $parentClass);
            }

            private static function SetPropertiesArray($class, $parentClass = null){
                $object             = new $class;
                $objectProperties   = get_object_vars($object);

                foreach($objectProperties as $prop => $value){
                    if(!is_null($parentClass)){
                        // CHECK IF $prop IS A CLASS...
                        if(class_exists($prop)){
                            self::$_propertiesArray[$parentClass][$class][$prop] = self::getClassPropertiesArray($prop, $parentClass);
                        }else{
                            self::$_propertiesArray[$parentClass][$class][$prop] = $value;
                        }
                    }else{
                        // CHECK IF $prop IS A CLASS...
                        if(class_exists($prop)){
                            self::$_propertiesArray[$class][$prop] = self::getClassPropertiesArray($prop, $parentClass);
                        }else{
                            self::$_propertiesArray[$class][$prop] = $value;
                        }

                    }
                }

                return self::$_propertiesArray;
            }

            private static function getClassPropertiesArray($class, $parentClass = null){
                $object             = new $class;
                $objectProperties   = get_object_vars($object);
                $arrClassProperties = array();

                foreach($objectProperties as $prop => $value){
                    $arrClassProperties[$prop] = $value;
                }
                return $arrClassProperties;
            }

            public function getPropertiesArray(){
                return self::$_propertiesArray;
            }
        }

        class Person{
            public $SurName  = "Test Surname";
            public $LastName = "BurgerServiceNummer" ;
            public $Address;
        }


        class Address{
            public $Street;
            public $ZipCode;
            public $City;
            public $Country;
        }
```

**THE VAR_DUMP ABOVE PRODUCES::**

```
        array (size=1)
          'Person' => 
            array (size=3)
              'SurName' => string 'Test Surname' (length=12)
              'LastName' => string 'BurgerServiceNummer' (length=19)
              'Address' => 
                array (size=4)
                  'Street' => null
                  'ZipCode' => null
                  'City' => null
                  'Country' => null
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution

```
<?php
function SearchArrayForKeyAndAdd(&$array, $given_key, $name, $data = null){
    foreach($array as $key => &$value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            if($key == $given_key){
                $value[$name] = $data;
            }
            else{
                SearchArrayForKeyAndAdd($value,$given_key, $name, $data);
            }

        }
        else{
            if($key == $given_key){
                $value[$name] = $data;
            }
        }
    }
}
$array = array(
    "person" => array(
        "Name" => "Roy Stijsiger",
        "Adress" => null
    )
);


SearchArrayForKeyAndAdd($array,"Adress","Huisnummer",1);

SearchArrayForKeyAndAdd($array,"Adress","Straatnaam","Nortierstraat");
var_dump($array);
```

This was dummy code^^
This is the working code like I showed above VV

```
private static function SetPropertiesArray($class,$parentClass = null){
        $object = new $class;
        $objectProperties = get_object_vars($object);
        foreach($objectProperties as $prop => $value){
            //echo $prop;
            if(class_exists($prop)){
                if($parentClass !== null){
                    self::SearchArrayForKeyAndAdd(self::$_propertiesArray,$parentClass,$prop,$value);
                }
                else{
                    self::$_propertiesArray[$prop] = $value;
                }
                self::SetPropertiesArray($prop,$prop);
            }
            else{
                if($parentClass !== null){
                    self::SearchArrayForKeyAndAdd(self::$_propertiesArray,$parentClass,$prop,$value);
                }
                else{
                    self::$_propertiesArray[$prop] = $value;
                }
            }
        }

        return self::$_propertiesArray;
    }

    private static function SearchArrayForKeyAndAdd(&$array, $given_key, $name, $data = null){
    foreach($array as $key => &$value){
        if(is_array($value)){
            if($key == $given_key){
                $value[$name] = $data;
            }
            else{
                self::SearchArrayForKeyAndAdd($value,$given_key, $name, $data);
            }
        }
        else{
            if($key == $given_key){
                $value[$name] = $data;
            }
        }
    }
```